# Java Filter a String for an url?

Tags: java, regex

Im working on a IRC-Bot for Twitch.tv

I just encountered a Problem.

I want to filter a String for a URL and then timeout the user who wrote the URL in the chat.
Searching on Google ive found out that i should probably use a Regex but i dont understand how to do that.

From another Question here on, i found out the regex to use is ;

```
"[a-zA-Z\d]+://(\w+:\w+@)?([a-zA-Z\d.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:\d+)?(/.*)?"
```

Can some1 give me any examples on how to use a regex to filter a string for unknown URLs?

It should be detect stuff like;

```
http://www.google.com
www.google.com
google.com
```

Any help is apreaciated and sorry for my bad english =p

Comment: Here you go: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: play with this for a little while http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
String regex = "([a-zA-Z\d]+://)?(\w+:\w+@)?([a-zA-Z\d.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:\d+)?(/.*)?"; 
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
```

// testedString is the message that person wrote and that you want to check for URL pattern

```
   Matcher m = p.matcher(testedString);
   if (m.find()) {
      // timout the user who inserted the URL
   }
```

By the way, more examples of detecting String with regex is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

Also I improved your URL pattern, now it will recognise all general URL strings

Answer (score 0):

The regex you included only matches really verbose URLs.  The beginning:

```
[a-zA-Z\d]+://
```

is matching one or more (that's the +) upper or lower case letters or digits (that's the part in brackets), followed by "://".  That is, it matches URLs starting with "http://" or "ftp://" or whatever.  If the string doesn't start with that, then it won't match.

Matching URLs in the general case is tricky.  You can't really tell the difference between a string like "for great deals go to --> dealz.biz" and "haha, that's hilarious.did you come up with that yourself?"  I think trying to auto-ban based on URLs is a bad idea.